# How can I change the color of the dot in an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of dots in an unordered list:

```html
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way that I can do this with CSS? I can't see a property?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The easiest (but rather unsemantic) way is to wrap the content in `span` tags, then apply the bullet color to `li` and text color to `span`.

In code:

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
    <li><span>text</span></li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul li {
    /* Bullet color */
    color: red;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

ul li span {
    /* Text color */
    color: black;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/RYh7U)

If you can't modify your HTML, you can either use `list-style-image` with a custom-colored dot, or use generated content (i.e. `li:before`) and color it accordingly (but watch out for list bullet position problems).

Here's [an example with `li:before`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/q9RRg):

```
ul li {
    /* Text color */
    color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:before {
    /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    content: '\2022 ';
    /* Bullet color */
    color: red;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I'll mark as correct but if you don't mind can u just explain the li:before. Would that mean I don't have to use span. What would be the positon problems.Thanks so much

Comment: The biggest problem with this solution is it doesn't work with multi-line bullets properly. The second line doesn't indent.

Comment: @Stuart McCoy: Yeah, that's a pain. I remember there being another answer to a similar question that tried to hack around that somehow, but I don't have a link handy yet.

Comment: Your first solution works perfectly for those who can't rely on E:before (such as in email). Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Further developing the answer given by @BoltClock:

```
ul li {
    color: black;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li:before {
    color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1em;
    width: 1em;
    content: '\2022';
}
```

In this way all lines of a multi-line bullet are indented properly. Beware: I’ve not had the chance to test it on IE yet!

Answer (score 3):

None of the above answers work for me, as I had content that wrapped onto multiple lines. However the solution provided by W3C is perfect:
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/color-bullets.en.html

In short, remove styling:

```
ul {list-style: none}
```

Then add your own bullet

```
li::before {
content: "•";
color: red;
display: inline-block;
width: 1em;
margin-left: -1em
}
```

The key points are inline-block, width and margin to position it correctly.

Comment: This doens't work on iPHones, it will use the iphone emoji equivalent.

Comment: It might be helpful to also indent the entire `li` element by setting `li { margin-left: 1em }` to offset the bullet. That way, the bullet gets aligned with the surrounding text / paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own image.

```
li {
    list-style-image: url(myImage.gif);
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a no image solution. Hope someone knows of one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    li::marker {
  color: #61dafb; //To change the color of bullet
  font-size: 2rem; //To change the size of the bullet
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker

Answer (score 1):

this did the trick for me:

```
ul li{
  color: var(--color-text);
}
li::marker{
  list-style: disc;  
  color: var(--color-blue);
}
```

instead of predefined vars you can enter the color code.

Comment: For me only first rule was enough

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a graphic:

http://catcode.com/csstips/graphic_list.html

As an aside, this will also give you granular control over the bullet positioning (by using margins and image offset).

Comment: I was looking for a no image solution. Hope someone knows of one. Thanks.