# Changing bullet color for an unordered list with li:before?

Tags: html, css

I just had one great solution on how to change the color of a bullet. The solution made note of another way.

"If you can't modify your HTML, you can either use list-style-image with a custom-colored dot, or use generated content (i.e. li:before) and color it accordingly (but watch out for list bullet position problems)."

Can someone explain this.

Thanks

Comment: I've already [edited my other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839553/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-dot-in-an-unordered-list/5839561#5839561) to answer this.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I just wanted to make it possible for you to have more points as it really is another question.

Answer (score 0):

This means that when you can only change the CSS and not the HTML, you can add contents with pure CSS.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/q9RRg/) the unicode character `\2022` which is   rendered as bullet is added before each list item and is colored red.

The CSS also hides any previous list item "marker" by the `list-style-type: none;` line above.