# List in html. How put dots with different colors but text is black?

Tags: html, css

My list:

```
<ul style="list-style:disc;">
    <li style="color:Red; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Отказано</li>
    <li style="color:#ADD8E6; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Установлено</li>
    <li style="color:#6B8E23; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Установлен частично</li>
    <li style="color:#B8860B; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Тестируется</li>
    <li style="color:#ADFF2F; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Готов</li>
</ul>
```

But text in list with color.

Comment: Explain you question in detail.

Comment: is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839553/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-dot-in-an-unordered-list) what you want?

Comment: @agreco i think he want different text color for each text item of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, it will help you...

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul.specials li p { color:black; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<ul style="list-style:disc;" class="specials">
    <li style="color:Red; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;"><p>Отказано</p></li>
    <li style="color:#ADD8E6; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;"><p>Установлено</p></li>
    <li style="color:#6B8E23; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;"><p>Установлен частично</p></li>
    <li style="color:#B8860B; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;"><p>Тестируется</p></li>
    <li style="color:#ADFF2F; margin-left: 7px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;"><p>Готов</p></li>
</ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class for the li color you want, and then have a span for the text color:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 2em;
}

li.a {
    color: red;
}

li.b {
    color: #ADD8E6;
}

li.c {
    color: #6B8E23;
}

ul li span {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/20/)