# How to change the color of numbers in ordered list without using counter in css?

Tags: css, html, dom

Am making an ordered list like the following

1. item1
2. item2
3. item3

I need to customize ordered list's numbering color with out affecting the default numbering.
 I want the result something like this.
see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/majis/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488830/ol-with-numbers-another-color) has some good answers. this one works without counters. Add an inner span with a different color.

```
<ol><li style='color: red;'><span style='color:black;'>test</span></li></ol>
```

Comment: than you see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/majis/?editors=111)

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K555P/)**

[**same question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725741/how-to-colour-the-list-style-type-auto-generated-numbers)

**HTML**

```
<ol id="footnotes">
    <li><span>This is the first footnote...</span></li>
    <li><span>This is the second footnote...</span></li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
#footnotes li { color: #f90; }
#footnotes li span { color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[In this post (*How can I change the color of the dot in an unordered list?*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839553/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-dot-in-an-unordered-list) was proposed a solution for bulleted list. Maybe could interesting for you too (but it require to add a span to each list-item)